Prove that the family of neighborhoods of $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb R$ does not have a countable basis.
Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a nonempty subset of $X$. A subset $V$ of $X$ is called a neighborhood of $A$ if there exists an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $A\subset U \subset V$. The set of neighborhoods of $A$ is $F$.
Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{N}$. Prove there does not exist a sequence $V_1,V_2,V_3\cdots$ of elements of $F$ such that every element of $F$ contains one of $V_i$.
This is an exercise from General Topology by Jacques Dixmier.
My attempt:
Prove by contradiction: suppose every element of $F$ contains one of the $V_i$. Then:
$$\mathbb{N}\subset \cap_{i=1}^\infty V_i\subset\cap_{i\in J}V_i\subset \cap F\subset \mathbb{N}$$ $J$ is an index set which is
$\{i\mid \exists V\in F, V_i\subset V\}$, so we have $\mathbb{N}= \cap_{i=1}^\infty V_i$.
How do we get the contradiction next?

This doesn't provide a contradiction:
if $V_i = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} (n-\frac{1}{i}, n+\frac{1}{i}) $, then $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb N} V_i = \mathbb N$.
Can you figure out, why this is not a counter-example of the theorem? This should guide you to a proof as well.

In your attempt, what is $J$? This doesn't make sense at all. As index set you have $\mathbb N$. Full stop!

@Ulli I define J, and I get stuck in getting a contradiction.

$J$, as you now defined it, is just $\mathbb N$ (with $F^\prime = \mathbb R$). Forget about $J$. Just consider my first comment.

This is NOT the same as what @AnneBauval mentions. There, the OP explicitely states that s/he wants to use some sequence of positive numbers to do the trick. I DO HAVE a very nice answer that does NOT USE the sequence of positive numbers and therefore DO NOT QUALIFY AS AN ANSWER to the pointed post.

@AndréCaldas  I vote to reopen it.

@noname1014: It seems you have approved the closing of it with one pending vote.

@AndréCaldas yes, because I have not seen your comment when I closed this.

@noname1014: I have post my answer here (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4945115/17092) please, up vote it. :-)

It is a shame that the police keeps shutting down legitimate contributors and legitimate contributions. :-(
